# C#.Net JSON Serialization not working

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, json-deserialization

Can someone tell me why i'm getting an error deserializing this JSON response?

```
    public T PostData<T>(string command, Dictionary<string, object> postData)
    {
        postData.Add("command", command);
        postData.Add("nonce", Helper.GetCurrentHttpPostNonce());

        var jsonString = PostString(Helper.ApiUrlHttpsRelativeTrading, postData.ToHttpPostString());
        var output = JsonSerializer.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonString);

        return output;
    }

    [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2202:Do not dispose objects multiple times")]
    internal static T DeserializeObject<T>(this JsonSerializer serializer, string value)
    { 
        using (var stringReader = new StringReader(value)) {
            using (var jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader(stringReader)) {
                /*   
                    An exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll but was not handled in user code
                    Additional information: Could not create an instance of type Jojatekok.PoloniexAPI.WalletTools.IBalance. Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated. Path '1CR.available', line 1, position 20. 

                    ERROR's ON NEXT LINE :
                */
                return (T)serializer.Deserialize(jsonTextReader, typeof(T));
            }
        }
    }
```

The string value coming back is:
{"1CR":"available":"0.00000000","onOrders":"0.00000000","btcValue":"0.00000000"}}

I have an interface for the balance:

```
public interface IBalance
{
    double QuoteAvailable { get; }
    double QuoteOnOrders { get; }
    double BitcoinValue { get; }
}
```

And a balance model:

```
public class Balance : IBalance
{
    [JsonProperty("available")]
    public double QuoteAvailable { get; private set; }
    [JsonProperty("onOrders")]
    public double QuoteOnOrders { get; private set; }
    [JsonProperty("btcValue")]
    public double BitcoinValue { get; private set; }
}
```

Although it's not deserializing the JSON to a Balance object.  i'm getting this error:

```
(An exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Could not create an instance of type Jojatekok.PoloniexAPI.WalletTools.IBalance. Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated. Path '1CR.available', line 1, position 20.)
```

This error is noted in the code where it occurs.
Any tips?

Comment: I'm guessing you call `DeserializeObject<IBalance>` but it must be `DeserializeObject<Balance>`. And why you don't using `JsonConvert`?

Comment: Hi Maxim, can you show how JsonConvert can be used in this context?

Answer (score 1):

I can see two close braces in your JSON string coming back:

```
{"1CR":"available":"0.00000000","onOrders":"0.00000000","btcValue":"0.00000000"}}
```

Source the `JSON.DeserializeObject<T>` it with a correct JSON Format string and I think it should work.

Comment: Hi Kunal, I copy/paste one json node for brevity, the actual JSON returned is too big to put here. I must have accidentally put the end bracket in. Assume the JSON is well formed

Answer (score 0):

Both the comment by Maxim Kosov and the answer by Kunal Chitkara seem correct, and I would add that the first token in the string

```
"1CR":"available":"0.00000000"
```

seems also incorrect, maybe it should be only

```
"available":"0.00000000"
```

In your original code, the comment mentions this as the probable cause of the error:

> Path '1CR.available', line 1, position 20.

Comment: Hi Carlos, I copy/paste one json node for brevity, the actual JSON returned is too big to put here. I must have accidentally put the end bracket in. Assume the JSON is well formed